# for each in js how iterte the and get value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I need to write to the dom for each idol in the array how can I do this with the for each look this is how I am doing right now but I need all the idols in the array.

```
  for (var i = 0; i  <  msg.response.idols.length; i++) {
     AddArtistField();
    document.getElementById("idols_" + i).value = msg.response.idols[i];
  }
```

Comment: storing the response after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to do this?

```
msg.response.idols.forEach( (idol, index) => { 
   AddArtistField();
   document.getElementById("idols_" + index).value = idol;
}
```